# How do I make it so a Variable = whats in a text box/text field?

Tags: php, variables, input, textbox

How do I make it so a Variable = whats in a text box/text field?

for example my text-field looks like this.

```
<input type="text" name="key" class="form-control" >
```

and my variable looks like this.

```
$key
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    ${$key} = $value; echo $key;
}exit;
```

Comment: Where about's should I place this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
     $key = $_POST['key'];
}
```

Much easier way.